# Replace a String (like g1) by adding a number (100) to it like (g101) in a file

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a file which contains gene names like g1, g2, g3, g1.t1, g2.t1, g3.t1 ..., I need to add 100 to each number beside "g" to be g101, g102, g103,g101.t1, g102.t1, g103.t1 ...
Here below are some lines from the file

start gene g1

Chr1    AUGUSTUS    gene    3656    5929    0.1 +   .   g1
Chr1    AUGUSTUS    transcript  3656    5929    0.1 +   .   g1.t1
Chr1    AUGUSTUS    tss 3656    3656    .   +   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";
Chr1    AUGUSTUS    exon    3656    3926    .   +   .   transcript_id "g1.t1"; gene_id "g1";

I need to use sed command to replace all g1, g2,.. in a file with the updated values.
does anyone have an idea?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

It is ugly and I'm sure there are much more elegant solutions but here is something to start with.

```
sed -i -e "s/[g]\([0-9]\)/g10\1/g" file
```

I am looking into doing actual arithmetic with sed which seems to be less than ideal. I would recommend looking into awk.

Answer (score 0):

This works on the supplied test data. Could be errors if there are several gene names in the same line, i.e. g1 and g10, but it does not look like that is the case.

```
gawk '{match($0,"g[0-9]+",ary);i=0;while(length(ary[i])>0){ gsub(ary[i],"g"(int(substr(ary[i],2))+100));i+=1}; print $0}' file
```

returns:

start gene g101

Chr1 AUGUSTUS gene 3656 5929 0.1 + . g101 Chr1 AUGUSTUS transcript 3656 5929 0.1 + . g101.t1 Chr1 AUGUSTUS tss 3656 3656 . + . transcript_id "g101.t1"; gene_id "g101"; Chr1 AUGUSTUS exon 3656 3926 . + . transcript_id "g101.t1"; gene_id "g101";

Answer (score 0):

```
snafu$ touch g1 g2 g3 g1.t1 g2.t1 g3.t1
snafu$ prename -v 's/g(\d+)/sprintf("g%03d",$1+100)/e' g* 
g1 renamed as g101
g1.t1 renamed as g101.t1
g2 renamed as g102
g2.t1 renamed as g102.t1
g3 renamed as g103
g3.t1 renamed as g103.t1
```

-n is a dry-run -- it'll show you the proposed renames without executing.

prename is included with perl.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/g(\d+)/"g".($1+100)/ge' file
```

Results:

```
start  gene      g101
Chr1   AUGUSTUS  gene        3656  5929  0.1  +  .  g101
Chr1   AUGUSTUS  transcript  3656  5929  0.1  +  .  g101.t1
Chr1   AUGUSTUS  tss         3656  3656  .    +  .  transcript_id  "g101.t1";  gene_id  "g101";
Chr1   AUGUSTUS  exon        3656  3926  .    +  .  transcript_id  "g101.t1";  gene_id  "g101";
```